# How to use dependency injection with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have troubles understanding how to properly implement a service in nodeJs.

So far, I have seen people create and export a class, but I have also seen people create a functionspace like this:

```
export const PersistenceService = {
    getCalculationResult: function getCalculationResult(name: string): number {
        // function body
      }
}
```

The functionspace can easily be imported into an express route:

```
calculationResult.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const result = PersistenceService.getCalculationResult("firstCalculation");
  res.satus(200).send(result);
}
```

I prefer using a functionspace over a class, because I don't have to worry about dependency injection. When using classes, I think, DI is important, because without it I could end up creating multiple instances of a class, well knowing that there just needs to be a single instance of my service class.

For example, if I wanted to replace the functionspace with a class, I might start with the following code:

```
calculationResult.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const result = new PersistenceService("firstCalculation");
  res.satus(200).send(result);
}
```

I don't want to instantiate a new object of my PersistenceService() class, however. Now, in order to inject this class, I need to make my calculationResult controller a class as well. This would be possible.

My question is: Is it common to create a controller class in nodeJs? Is it possible to use this functionspace I mentioned instead?

I'm aware that the answer to this question might be biased, it should be possible to point out a few advantages over some disadvantes though, am I right?

Comment: There are controller classes now, but Node's Express was not built around them, as they didn't even exist. It was ES6, especially with Typescript, that brought a massive influx of class-based tools.

Comment: `export const PersistenceService = new PersistenceService("firstCalculation");` and keep your class definition privately.

Comment: "well knowing that there just needs to be a single instance of my service class" - why? Possibly a difficulty here is that you try to bring DI pattern where it doesn't belong. `name` is just a parameter here. DI can be implemented with function params but DI != params. Express is functional, you won't benefit from controller classes, check Nestjs if you're interested in that. You can use PersistenceService class here the way you do if you want but there's no benefit from using it because it's immediately serialized in a response. If you still have difficulties, consider explaining your case

Comment: allright, thx  for your explanation, guys! I might have to read up on functional programming patterns.